# Spawn at certain distance

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am developing a game where I need to spawn an infinite number of planes.I manage to spawn the plane but I want them to spawn at a certain distance from one another, like one unit away from one another.Looking forward to hearing from you.

```
public GameObject[] tileprefabs;
private Transform playerTransform;
private float spawnz = 10.0f;
private float tileLength = 7.0f;
private float amnoftilesOnScreen = 20.0f ;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    playerTransform = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("player").transform;
    for(int i=0; i<amnoftilesOnScreen; i++)
    {
        spawntiles();
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if(playerTransform.position.z>(spawnz - amnoftilesOnScreen*tileLength))
    {
        spawntiles();
    }
}

private void spawntiles(int prefabIndex = -1) {
    GameObject go = Instantiate(tileprefabs[0] as GameObject);
    go.transform.SetParent(transform);
    go.transform.position = Vector3.forward * spawnz;
    spawnz += tileLength;
}
```

Comment: Could you also include the code that you used to spawn the plane yourself? That will aid in filling in the gaps to answer your question.

Comment: private void spawntiles(int prefabIndex = -1)
    {
        GameObject go;
        go = Instantiate(tileprefabs[0] as GameObject);
        go.transform.SetParent(transform);
        go.transform.position = Vector3.forward * spawnz;
        spawnz += tileLength;
    }

Comment: spawntiles is responsible for spawning the plane.

Comment: Show the `spawntiles()` function, because *that's the important bit* of your code that needs adjustment. And edit it into your question. Parsing it from your comment is impossible.

Comment: I got the solution eventually. I just changed the value of the tileLength.Here's the code....private float tileLength = 7.0f;